# Database BCNF Violations

Tags: relational-database, bcnf

I am confused about a particular aspect of DB BCNF violation criteria. Here's an example:

`R(ABCDEF)`

The FDs are `BC->D, C->AF, AB->CE`.

I have derived the candidate keys to be `AB and BC`.

The relation is in BCNF right, given all of the FDs contain at least part of the candidate keys?

Thanks guys!

Comment: *"I have derived the candidate keys to be `AB->CE or BC->D`."* Those are functional dependencies, not candidate keys. There might be more than one candidate key. You don't choose from them; you identify *all* of them.

Comment: *" . . . the relation is still in BCNF right, given all of the FDs contain at least part of the LHS of the candidate key?"* No, it's in BCNF if the arrow in every FD is an arrow out of a candidate key. In this case R is not in BCNF, because the arrow in `C->AF` is not an arrow out of a candidate key. (C is not a candidate key in R.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the correction. I have edited the question as such, but the CKs are still AB and BC. So, in order for R to be in BCNF, the LHS of all FDs must contain at least one of the FULL candidate keys (in this case, either AB or BC)?

Comment: And one more thing, if I want to find out the violations in R, should I select one CK and compare all the FDs against that CK, or should I use all of the CKs when comparing the FDs? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You derived the right keys: AB and BC.

> The relation is in BCNF right, given all of the FDs contain at least
>   part of the candidate keys?

No. Informally, a relation is in BCNF if and only if the arrow in every FD is an arrow out of a candidate key. In other words, a relation is in BCNF if and only if the left-hand side of every functional dependency is a candidate key. The left-hand side of `C->AF` is C, but C is not a candidate key. So R is not in BCNF.

(From a comment by the OP . . .)

> And one more thing, if I want to find out the violations in R, should
>   I select one CK and compare all the FDs against that CK, or should I
>   use all of the CKs when comparing the FDs?

Use all the candidate keys. Normalization always considers *all* the candidate keys.

Comment: If a relation is in BCNF, there exists a functional dependency X -> Y for all X belonging to the superkey (not only a candidate key).